# React Native - CameraRoll - Access base64 version of image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using RN Camera Roll (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html) to access a series of images for selection as part of a form.  My question is - does anyone know if it's possible to access the base64 of the image - or the easiest method of conversion in this scenario.

Here is my usePhotos class:

```
 usePhotos = () => {
  CameraRoll.getPhotos({
      first: 20,
      assetType: 'Photos',
    })
    .then(r => {
      this.setState({ ADModalState:false,
        ADMediaCamera:false, isModalVisible:true, ADphotos: r.edges, ADPhotosBase:r.edges });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
       //Error Loading Images
       console.warn(err);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my eventual workaround:

```
if(Platform.OS === 'ios'){
      if (uriPhoto.startsWith('ph://'))
      {
        imagePATH = uriPhoto.substring(5,41);
        let photoPATH = `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=${imagePATH}&ext=JPG`;

        const dest = `${RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}.jpg`;

        RNFS.copyAssetsFileIOS(photoPATH, dest, 500, 500, 1.0, 1.0, 'contain')
          .then(data => {
            RNFS.readFile(data, 'base64')
              .then(base64 => {

                this.state.ADImageArray.push(uriPhoto);
                this.props.encodedImage(base64);

                //TODO - Delete file
              });
          });
      }
    }
    else if(Platform.OS === 'android'){

      RNFS.readFile(uriPhoto, 'base64')
        .then(base64 => {
          this.state.ADImageArray.push(uriPhoto);
          this.props.encodedImage(base64);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible with RN Camera Form, but what I used as a solution a year ago was this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-base64 
It is stil downloaded quite a lot so I assume it is still functioning

Comment: Thanks @Uber - looks like it would be perfect - but i get this error when running a pod install - [!] The `RNImgToBase64` pod failed to validate due to 1 error:
    - ERROR | attributes: Missing required attribute `homepage`.
    - WARN  | source: The version should be included in the Git tag.
    - WARN  | github_sources: Github repositories should end in `.git`.

Comment: @Dancer I will grab my mac from the old closet and try it out will get back to you

Comment: @Dancer I made a simple podfile for it! Put this file in the root of the react-native-image-base64 folder inside node_modules https://a.uguu.se/Im0GbOqKSv8b_RNImgToBase64.podspec link will only work for 24h so be quick ;)

Comment: ahh - cheers for your help / effort @ Uber - but I just get this error now : [!] No podspec found for `RNImgToBase64` in `../node_modules/react-native-image-base64` . - did it work for you?

Comment: @Dancer yes it the pod did install without any errors, will upload my complete module folder for you to try out in about 30 minutes

Comment: @Dancer https://filebin.net/2bbe3aj3um9eykzk there you go let me know how it goes else we'll find another solution (in javascript there are also ways to do it when I took a quick look onlione)

Comment: Cheers for all your help @Uber - still cant get the pod to install - randomly stops with  
――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

..  - Might look for a plan B with another library.. cheers

Comment: fyi fiddled with the pod and got it to load (missing home ref) but still doesnt work - now get null is not an object app error...

Comment: @Dancer hmhm... I am just leaving work to go back home and will explore another option will get back to you